# Connect to an external website with PHP

Tags: php, authentication, fetch

Let say i have a website (called s1.com..?) with a login form. After you succesfully log on the website, you have a page with some status infos like : Ticket Closed. since...
And then ai have a page, on another server that need to go on s1.com, log me in and then retreive the date if the ticket is closed...

I dont really need all of the script since i think i can figure it out, but i wonder how do i make the first part, connecting the webpage onto the s1.com webpage so ill be able to fetch data?

Thanks for any help guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can use either [curl](http://au.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) (link has an example) or [fopen](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) (see the examples section).

Note that using `fopen` requires that the [allow_url_fopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) setting to be enabled, while `curl` requires the `curl` module to be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can also Use **JSONP with jQuery**, this is alternative of CURL ( i may b wrong ) here is some useful links

- [First Link](http://niryariv.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/jsonp-quickly/)
- [Second Link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/107136.aspx)
- [Third Link](http://ajax.sys-con.com/node/1410501)