# Retrieve a Get Http request in php

Tags: php, javascript

I need to retrieve a get http request in php and store it in a variable.

I need to execute the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=client_credentials
```

I know this is simple. just not able to get my head around it.

Comment: Use CURL - see here for documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to an external website with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882218/connect-to-an-external-website-with-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials');
```

Comment: @atif089: Of course `file_get_contents` is the right choice. cURL is a mammoth compared to `file_get_contents`, there is no need for all that functionality to do this trivial task. :)

Answer (score 2):

Within the Open Graph protocol page on Facebook, there is an example within the documentation coded using PHP: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

```
<?php

$ogurl = "INSERT_YOUR_OG_URL_HERE";
define(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, "YOUR_APP_ID_HERE");
define(FACEBOOK_SECRET, "YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE");

$mymessage = "Hello World!";

$access_token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token"; 
$parameters = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" . FACEBOOK_APP_ID ."&client_secret=" . FACEBOOK_SECRET;
$access_token = file_get_contents($access_token_url . "?" . $parameters);

$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/feed";
$parameters = "?" . $access_token . "&message=" . urlencode($mymessage) . "&id=" . $ogurl . "&method=post";
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;

$result = file_get_contents($myurl);

// output the post id
echo "post_id" . $result;
}
?>
```

The key line in actually making the call being:

```
$result = file_get_contents($myurl);
```

There is also a good amount of other information about the resulting object you get back there that would be good to take a look into.

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($fp = fopen('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
 client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&
 grant_type=client_credentials', 'r')) {
   $content = '';
   // keep reading until there's nothing left 
   while ($line = fread($fp, 1024)) {
      $content .= $line;
   }

   // do something with the content here
   // ... 
} else {
   // an error occured when trying to open the specified url 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like

```
$client_id = $_GET['client_id'];
$client_secret = $_GET['client_secret'];
$grant_type = $_GET['grant_type'];
```

?

Or rather something like

```
$content = file_get_contents($url);
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
$id = $_GET['client_id'];
$type = $_GET['grant_type'];
$secret = $_GET['client_secret'];
```

Hope this helps you